# I want to change color within the value text shown in the text area. such as shown in the image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel-5

I want to change color within the value shown in the text area. such as shown in the image.

```
<textarea id="pageTitle" name="pageTitle"  rows="5" class="form-control" >{{ "Buy ".$genericbrandData->genericBrand." ".$imporvised_genericStrength. " online- Generic ".$genericbrandData->genericName."- ".$genericbrandData->genericCompany }} </textarea>
```

[output is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DYRO.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vJ51.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using color keywords to change the text to red, green, blue, or some other basic color will not give you the precision you may be looking for when creating different shades of those colors. That's what hexadecimal values are for.

> eg:

```
p { 
  color: #000000; 
}
```